# Looking for IOS framework for one off tweets in kiosk setting (ie no O/XAuth)

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, twitter

Are there any ios frameworks for single tweets (and/or facebook likes).

I needs something appropriate for kiosk style application. So I need to be able to say to the api, given this user/pass post this tweet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell: http://getsharekit.com/

(Wow, I never noticed what a weird expression "in a nutshell" is..)

Comment: +1 for "(Wow, I never noticed what a weird expression "in a nutshell" is..)"

Comment: That was my first thought but is there any way to share without using OAuth. I don't want to register any user to the application I just need to provide an interface for people to tweet at a kiosk.

Answer (score 0):

There's the [Twitter Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TwitterFrameworkReference/_index.html) if you're targeting iOS 5